# Docker window access webcam

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to access my webcam from within a Docker container running on Windows, and then use the cv2 library to work with the camera data. I've tried several approaches so far, but none of them have worked for me. While I've found many resources discussing how to do this on Linux, there's much less information available for Windows. I don't want to resort to using an IP webcam since that would be too slow.

I only saw dev/video0 which didn't work.

Comment: Could you please share the your docker run command that you have executed with in Windows?  Have you installed Xming or X11 forwarding agent?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the below option when running the docker image.

```
docker run -it \
...

--env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
--env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
-v /dev/video0:/dev/video0 \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro \
-v $(pwd):/workspace
...
```

If you already mount your host folder using your own command, then you can skip the last line `$(pwd):/workspace`.

Comment: However, the OP asks how to do that on Windows

Comment: In this case, you may install the VirtualBox and follow this link. Address: https://medium.com/@jijupax/connect-the-webcam-to-docker-on-mac-or-windows-51d894c44468